# GraphQLNonNull opposite

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

i`m trying implements graphql and i have problem.

I did type for graphql:

```
export const menuItemDataType = new GraphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'MenuItemData',
    fields: () => ({
        staticUrl: {
            type: GraphQL.GraphQLString
        },
        page: {
            type: new GraphQL.GraphQLNonNull(menuItemType),
            resolve(MenuItemData) {
                return PageRepository.getPageById(MenuItemData.page).exec();
            }
        },
        menu: {
            type: new GraphQL.GraphQLNonNull(menuType),
            resolve(MenuItemData) {
                return MenuRepository.getMenuById(MenuItemData.menu).exec();
            }
        }
    })
})
```

and in this GraphQLObjectType i have **page** and **menu**.
I use mongoDB with mongoose. **page** and **menu** are nullable in model. When i query in graphql on this property so its chance that can be return null, but this is not compatible with GraphQL.GraphQLNonNull. Return error with "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field MenuItemData.page."

My question is: "Is any opposite for GraphQLNonNull. Like GraphQL?". I didnt found it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `GraphQLNonNull` if the type is nullable. GraphQL fields can have no value by default.

```
type: new GraphQL.GraphQLNonNull(menuType)
```

becomes

```
type: menuType
```